# Склонение фамилии "Иногда"

Tags: склонение, склонение-фамилий

Здравствуйте. Будет ли склоняться фамилия Иногда? Например: Василий Иногда (диссертация Василия Иногда или диссертация Василия Иногды)

Comment: Всем спасибо за участие

Answer (score 4):

Среди фамилий с ударным **á** после согласных есть как морфологически членимые, так и нечленимые, т. е. несклоняемые.

Несклоняемы фамилии французского происхождения:
Дюма, Тома, Дега, Люка, Ферма, Гамарра, Петипа и др.

Фамилии иного происхождения (славянские, из восточных языков) склоняются по первому склонению, т. е. в них вычленяется ударное окончание **-а**:
Митта — Митты, Митте, Митту, Миттой;
сюда относятся: Сковорода, Кочерга, Кваша, Цадаса, Хамза и др.
[Особенности склонения фамилий и личных имен](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_482)

Однако в данном случае (если это ударное **-А**) фамилия не от существительного, а от наречия, думаю, она несклоняема, как и исходное слово. Это нестандартная фамилия, для таких фамилий нет правил, но лучше не склонять, это более оправдано морфологией исходного слова.

Comment: Видел эту статью, но сомнений не развеяла. Спасибо за мнение, за ответ

Comment: Отбрось сомненья, всяк сюда входящий.   )))

Людмила, эта фамилия не от наречия. Это скорее всего украинская фамилия по типу Карацюпа или Масибута. Ударение, вероятно, на первый слог. Хотя может быть и на второй.

Comment: Почему ж не от наречия? Я вот где-то однажды встретила фамилию ИногдЫ, заинтересовалась, нашла объяснение:от клички, кличку дали предку за то, что часто произносил "иногды"(так звучит слово в диалекте по Фасмеру:
иногда́ диал. иногды́, др.-русск. иногда "однажды, в другой раз". Связано с ино́й "другой", ин "один". Образование на -гда можно объяснить как всегда́. Скорее всего, от обобщенного *-къда, а не от год.Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс. М. Р. Фасмер. 1964—1973). Может, и здесь от клички, но уже не в диалектном звучании, а в литературном.

Comment: Если в рамках вопроса о склонении, то уже потому, что можно хоть бессмысленную последовательность звуков сделать фамилией, это ничего не изменит. А если вообще, то фамилии от наречий не образуются. А если и образуется, то вы можете поручиться, что нет какого-нибудь областного существительного, созвучного этому наречию?

Comment: Иногда ( наречие )  став  прозвищем,  а  затем  и  фамилией, стала  обыкновенным  существительным,  и  должно  склоняться  по  общему  правилу.

Answer (score 4):

Фамилия (мужская и женская) склоняется независимо от происхождения и ударения. 
Как и ***все фамилии, заканчивающиеся на А***, ударное и безударное.
Единственное закрепленное правилами отступление от правил: французские фамилии, что объясняется не грамматикой, а историческими причинами. Ну еще некоторые односложные фамилии, преимущественно восточного происхождения. Все остальные подобные фамилии склоняются независимо от происхождения и места ударения.

Дело не в статье, а в том, что норма склонения закреплена правилами русского языка, а не просто мнением отдельных авторов. Кстати, я правильно понимаю, что носитель произносит эту фамилию с ударным И? Вроде бы мне приходилось с ней сталкиваться.

//---------------
Решил добавить.  В упомянутой ссылке на Еськову (источник, кстати довольно древний - 1990 г.) я не согласен по сути только с одним положеним - и всем что из него вытекает.

> Разрешение таких затруднений не может быть обеспечено правилами, для этого необходим словарь фамилий, дающий нормативные рекомендации для каждого слова.

[Письмовник | gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_482)

Не должно быть затруднений, решаемых в слованом порядке. Должно быть правило или исчерпывающий список правил со всеми возможными правилами-оговорками - и столь же исчерпывающий список исключений. Я, кстати, где-то привордил вполне исчерпывающий список возможных правил-исключений.

И еше. **И**ногда - все-таки прежде всего река в бассейне Енисея. 
В Вики про неё нет, но в сети - многочисленные упоминания.

- http://fotki.yandex.ru/users/lisihka04/view/161951/?page=1
- http://crosswords.coolreferat.com/baza/116428

Я скорее поверю в речную версию, чем в наречие. если это изначально не фейк, 
конечно.

Comment: Именно на А. Как наречие звучит. Если бы ударение было на И, то не было бы вообще вопросов)

Comment: Тем не менее считаю, что фамилия должна склоняться. Мотивация - в тексте ответа.

Comment: Ваша мотивация основывается на правилах,но примеры в правилах все для фамилий от существительных,а они бывают и от других частей речи, поэтому и называются нестандартными.

Comment: Вы, имхо, неправильно трактуете общее и частное. Примеры - это частное, они не описывают правило, только его иллюстрируют. Нельзя же ставить под сомнение правило в отношении любого случая, который не описан в примерах?

Примеры - это примеры. В них нет примеров на фамилии, предположим, с твердым знаком. И что, такие фамилии не склоняются?  Адъютантов к примеру?
  
Короче, в правилах нет оговорок, что склоняются только фамилии от существительных. Фамилия вообще может быть вообще иноязычная, но тем не менее склоняться. Поэтому полагаю, что и рассматриваемая фамилия склоняется.

Comment: В данном случае я за склонение данной фамилии. Во-первых, в соответствии с правилом. Во-вторых,  именно потому, что есть четкая ассоциация с омонимичным наречием. Спроси у ИногдЫ, на мой взгляд, звучит лучше, чем спроси у ИногдА.

Comment: Ларf, это все хорошо, но вообще-то разговор об ***общих*** правилах... 
Либо правило о регулярном склонении фамилий на -а имеет специальное изъятие на этот случай - либо нет. Третьего как-то не дано. Нельзя же руководствоваться личными ощущениями.

Answer (score 0):

Фамилия Иногда не склоняется:Василия Иногда, Василием Иногда, Василию Иногда...

Comment: Не  склоняется,  если  носитель  фамилии  -  женщина.

Comment: Нет, правила о несколнении конкретно женских фамилий подобного рода не существует. Вы, видимо, перенесли на этот случай правило о женских фамилиях на согласный.

Comment: Согласен  с  вами.